# Google Cardboard SDK start screen

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript, google-cardboard

Sorry, I am very new to Unity and coding in general. Here is what I came up with to make a startscreen but, I have no clue were to put the get.component.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class Click : MonoBehaviour
{
// If onCardBoardTrigger is active
public void onCardboardTrigger() {
        if  (isLookingAtObject()) {}
        RollerCoasterOne.GetComponent<Click>().isLookingAtObject();
        //Then go to HorrorCoaster
    else  
        SceneManager.LoadScene("HorrorCoaster"); 
    }
}
//This is meant to be a simple start me
```

http://pastebin.com/wMndr6Jm

Comment: Please post your code here. Use ticks to mark your code or highlight your code and click the `{}` button in the text editor.

Comment: Have a look at the Demo Scene provided by Google in the Cardboard SDK. That should give you a good start.